# DisclosureGroup loading/preloading content behavior in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui

I am working with a disclosureGroup as follows:

```
    var body: some View {
        List(routes) { route in
            DisclosureGroup(
                content: {
                    RouteImageView(route: route)
                },
                label: {
                    RouteNameView(route: route)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

What I would like to know is the behavior behind loading the content in this disclosure group in terms of whether all content is loaded immediately or if content is loaded on demand when a label is clicked.  RouteNameView only displays the text of a route, but RouteImageView fetches an image from my Firebase storage and displays it.

When a user opens this page, will all images for all routes be preloaded immediately (and thereby consuming lots of their roaming data), or will the images only be loaded when the content is expanded in the DisclosureGroup?

Comment: Is route a class or a structure. As all routes are needed to set the rows even it is only the name which is needed. Difference between class and structure will be that for class only a pointer may be copied to subview for classes vs all structure copied for structure. If RoutNameView beds only the name, the optimisation would be to use only the name in call.

Comment: route is a struct, and that struct contains a url value that I use to fetch an image in RouteImageView

Comment: One other thing: only one image view exists at one time and freed when navigation return.

Comment: It is my understanding that a `DisclosureGroup` is lazy loaded. If you put an `.onAppear()` inside the `DisclosureGroup`, it won't trigger until the `DisclosureGroup` is opened. You can test that yourself.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Yrb